# Find the manager details where all the employees under the manager should have salary more than 1000

Tags: sql, select, group-by

Im having the table with records like below

```
EMPNO   ENAME   JOB         MGR HIREDATE        SAL     COMM    DEPTNO
7369    SMITH   CLERK       7902    17-DEC-80   800  -  20
7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN    7698    20-FEB-81   1600    300     30
7521    WARD    SALESMAN    7698    22-FEB-81   1250    500     30
7566    JONES   MANAGER     7839    02-APR-81   2975     -      20
7654    MARTIN  SALESMAN    7698    28-SEP-81   1250    1400    30
7698    BLAKE   MANAGER     7839    01-MAY-81   2850     -      30
7782    CLARK   MANAGER     7839    09-JUN-81   2450     -      10
7788    SCOTT   ANALYST     7566    19-APR-87   3000     -      20
7839    KING    PRESIDENT    -      17-NOV-81   5000     -      10
7844    TURNER  SALESMAN    7698    08-SEP-81   1500     0      30
7876    ADAMS   CLERK       7788    23-MAY-87   1100     -      20
7900    JAMES   CLERK       7698    03-DEC-81   950  -   30 
7902    FORD    ANALYST     7566    03-DEC-81   3000     -      20
7934    MILLER  CLERK       7782    23-JAN-82   1300     -      10
```

and i need to get the manager details where the all the employees under the manager should have salary more than 1000

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Btw, those are _rows_, not _records_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses a correlated subquery:

```
select e.*
from emp e
where (select min(e1.sal) from emp e1 where e1.mgr = e.empno) >= 1000
```

This ensures that:

- the selected employee is a manager (ie they manage at least one employee)
- all of the managees of the manager have a salary above (or equal to) 1000